# Trouble finding a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm having some trouble solving the following question:

> Given $$\vec{u_1} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}, \quad\vec{u_2} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}, \quad\vec{u_3} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}, \quad\vec{u_4} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix},$$ is there any linear transformation $L$ such that $L\left(u_1\right)=u_2$ and $L\left(u_3\right)=u_4$?

I don't really know where to begin with the problem and would appreciate some leads on where to begin.

Comment: Please include your efforts, or some form of context.  Please understand, this site is not a "do my work for me" service.

Comment: @amWhy sorry, I forgot to include that but I've now updated my post. Thank you for your feedback! :)

Comment: $T[u_1 \,\,u_3] = [u_2 \,\,u_4]$, $T$ is a $3$x$3$ matrix.

Comment: @Arthur thank you, we will try it right away! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

$$T(x,y,z)=(x,x-y,x+y-z)$$